# A new page is loaded using from a button in iframe, but the selenium driver doesn't load the page source of new page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write a webdriver using selenium + python. I switched to an iFrame using `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='iframe[id="iframe_id"]'))`. Inside the iframe, I'm doing the following (just filling a form):-

```
l = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='button[id="enter-passcode"]')
l.click()
l = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='passcode-input')
l.send_keys('12345678')
l.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

After submitting the form, the page loads to a new page. I then switch to the parent frame by `driver.switch_to.parent_frame()`. I expect the new page html code to be loaded in the driver but the driver code still shows the iframe code, so I'm not able to do anything on the new page. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The new iframe is not inside the first iframe, so after submitting the form with

```py
l.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

You need to switch to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Now, in case you need to switch into a new iframe you can do it with something like

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='iframe[id="new_iframe_id"]'))
```

Otherwise you can simply work inside the default content you switched to by the previous `driver.switch_to.default_content()` command.

Comment: Tried doing that, but the driver seems to still be stuck on the iframe